# Is it possible to read the database name from a mdf file that is not attached to a sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a batch file I am running to shrink a large number of detached database log files. I first attach the database with a "default_database_name", then shrink the database, then detach it again and move onto the next database.

This accomplishes shrinking all my log files, however, then all my databases end up having the same logical database name. I am trying to avoid this.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you know the name of the file, e.g. `database1.mdf`, why not just use everything before the `.mdf` as the database name?

Comment: Well the idea is to be able to run a script to shrink about 100 log files and they all are associated with different db files. Like db1.mdf db1.ldf, db2.mdf db2.ldf, db3.mdf db3.ldf...

Comment: Right, and if you can load `'db1.mdf'`, `'db2.mdf'`, etc. into dynamic SQL that attaches a database, you can also load `'db1'`, `'db2'`, etc. into the `CREATE DATABASE x FOR ATTACH` statement, right?

Comment: Okay, I understand what you are saying. Unfortunately all the databases have the same physical file name. They are differentiated by the folders they are located in.

Comment: Then use the *folder* name as part of the name.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this information, but you will have to use a hex editor to see it, for the databases I tested with I opened the MDF with a hex editor (HxD was the one I used) and the database name was visible at around offset 00000E20-00000E30:

[image: Hex Screenshot]

Comment: Although, how useful this is for a batch file, I'm not sure.

Comment: Well I guess, it is possible! But like you stated, I don't think I will attempt to incorporate this method into my batch file. Thanks for the effort.